# Hide Road shapefile after create it's network in NetLogo

Tags: gis, netlogo

I would like to clear shape file in NetLogo world but i can not do this.
network line (on road shape file) is created and match with road shape file. Now i should clear road shape file and keep just road network.
can u help me to do this?

with respect regard

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2wmi.png)

```
extensions [ gis ]
globals [ roads-dataset scooter-dataset ]
breed [ nodes node ]
breed [ scooters scooter ]
breed [ walkers walker ]
walkers-own [ wlocation ]
scooters-own [slocation]

to setup
  ; reset
  clear-all
  reset-ticks

  ; load data set
;  gis:load-coordinate-system ("WGS 1984.prj")
  set roads-dataset gis:load-dataset "layer/road.shp"
  ;set scooter-dataset gis:load-dataset "layer/lands.shp"
  gis:set-world-envelope (gis:envelope-of roads-dataset)

  ; draw data set
  gis:set-drawing-color blue
  gis:draw roads-dataset 1

  make-road-network
  
end


to make-road-network
  clear-links
  let first-node nobody
  let previous-node nobody
  foreach gis:feature-list-of roads-dataset [ ; each polyline
    foreach gis:vertex-lists-of ? [ ; each polyline segment / coordinate pair
      foreach ? [ ; each coordinate
        let location gis:location-of ?
        if not empty? location [ ; some coordinates are empty []
          create-nodes 1 [
            set color green
            set size 1
            set xcor item 0 location
            set ycor item 1 location
            set hidden? true
            if first-node = nobody [
              set first-node self
            ]
            if previous-node != nobody [
              create-link-with previous-node
            ]
            set previous-node self
          ]
        ]
      ]
      set previous-node nobody
    ]
  ]
  ; connect adjacent polylines/roads
  ask nodes [ create-links-with other nodes in-radius 0.001 ]
end
```

Answer (score 0):

just remove the line gis:set-drawing-color blue

Best,
A

Comment: This answer could be improved if you explain _why_ that line should be removed.